QAOA for 3 cities TSP not working
I am trying to learn QAOA algorithm, and trying to code by reading the content at https://learning.quantum.ibm.com/tutorial/quantum-approximate-optimization-algorithm
The code I am writing to simulate on my local machine:
    import numpy as np
    from qiskit_aer import Aer
    from qiskit_aer.primitives import sampler
    from qiskit_algorithms import QAOA, NumPyMinimumEigensolver
    from qiskit_algorithms.optimizers import optimizer
    from qiskit_optimization.algorithms import MinimumEigenOptimizer
    from qiskit_optimization.applications import Tsp
    from qiskit_optimization.converters import QuadraticProgramToQubo
    from qiskit.circuit.library.n_local.qaoa_ansatz import QAOAAnsatz
    from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Session

     n = 3
     num_qubits = n ** 2
     distance_matrix = np.array([
     [0, 48, 91],
     [48,  0, 63],
     [91, 63,  0],])
     tsp=Tsp(distance_matrix)
     qp = tsp.to_quadratic_program()
     print(qp.prettyprint())
     qp2qubo = QuadraticProgramToQubo()
     qubo = qp2qubo.convert(qp)
     print(qubo.prettyprint())

     cost_hamiltonian, offset = qubo.to_ising()
     print(offset)
     print(cost_hamiltonian)

     circuit = QAOAAnsatz(cost_operator=cost_hamiltonian, reps=2)
     circuit.measure_all()
     circuit.parameters
     from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
     backend = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator_statevector')
     print(backend)
     pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(optimization_level=3,backend=backend)
     candidate_circuit = pm.run(circuit)
     candidate_circuit.draw('mpl', fold=False, idle_wires=False)
     initial_gamma = np.pi
     initial_beta = np.pi/2
     init_params = [initial_gamma, initial_beta, initial_gamma, initial_beta]

     def cost_func_estimator(params, ansatz, hamiltonian, estimator):

    # transform the observable defined on virtual qubits to
    # an observable defined on all physical qubits
    isa_hamiltonian = hamiltonian.apply_layout(ansatz.layout)

    pub = (ansatz, isa_hamiltonian, params)
    job = estimator.run([pub])

    results = job.result()[0]
    cost = results.data.evs
    print(cost)

    objective_func_vals.append(cost)

    return cost

    from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Session, EstimatorV2 as Estimator  
    from scipy.optimize import minimize  
    from qiskit_ibm_runtime import SamplerV2 as Sampler  

    objective_func_vals = [] # Global variable  
    with Session(backend=backend) as session:  
    # If using qiskit-ibm-runtime<0.24.0, change `mode=` to `session=`  
    estimator = Estimator(mode=session)  
    estimator.options.default_shots = 1000  

    # Set simple error suppression/mitigation options
        result = minimize(
        cost_func_estimator,
        init_params,
        args=(candidate_circuit, cost_hamiltonian, estimator),
        method="COBYLA",
        tol=1e-6,
    )
    print(result)
    optimized_circuit = candidate_circuit.assign_parameters(result.x)
    sampler = Sampler(mode=session)
    sampler.options.default_shots = 10000

    pub= (optimized_circuit, )
    job = sampler.run([pub], shots=int(1e4))
    counts_int = job.result()[0].data.meas.get_int_counts()
    counts_bin = job.result()[0].data.meas.get_counts()
    shots = sum(counts_int.values())
    final_distribution_int = {key: val/shots for key, val in counts_int.items()}
    final_distribution_bin = {key: val/shots for key, val in counts_bin.items()}
    print(final_distribution_int)

    # Find the bitstring with the highest probability
    most_likely_bitstring_int = max(final_distribution_int, key=final_distribution_int.get)
    most_likely_bitstring_bin = max(final_distribution_bin, key=final_distribution_bin.get)
    print(f"Most likely bitstring (int): {most_likely_bitstring_int}")
    print(f"Most likely bitstring (binary): {most_likely_bitstring_bin}")

The result I am getting:
      message: Optimization terminated successfully.
      success: True
      status: 1
      fun: -1304.0579420579418
      x: [ 2.521e+00  1.384e+00  2.585e+00  1.050e+00]
      nfev: 58
      maxcv: 0.0

      Most likely bitstring (int): 393
      Most likely bitstring (binary): 110001001

Where is the issue? Can somebody explain? I get the feeling it has something to do with the session, estimator and sampler commands.

What exactly is going wrong here? It seems to me that the circuit is indeed being optimised and returns a bitstring.
From experience with QAOA it sounds like the bitstring you are getting is not the one you expected to (i.e. the exact solution to the problem at hand)

TL;DR: At first sight it seems to me that your execution is working. However, there are interesting details to know about QAOA.
There are many things involved in QAOA not reaching the expected optimal value.
Quantum Approximate Optimisation Algorithm
As its name suggests, the algorithm is an approximate optimisation algorithm. This means that in the best case you may still never be able to land on the exact quantum state that results in the expected solution state with 100% of your measurements. This comes from the fact that the expressivity of your QAOA circuit is limited, therefore not reaching every possible quantum state. I believe that the original QAOA paper describes the reduction of the algorithm to an annealing procedure when p goes to infinity. The larger p, the more expressive your circuit gets (also increasing the number of optimisation parameters).
Quantum Approximate Optimisation Algorithm
This is all assuming that your optimiser converges to the global optimum, which is in turn not guaranteed in most cases. Let's now assume the optimal state is "in reach" of the specific QAOA circuit you chose. your optimiser may get stuck in a local minimum that isn't the expected state or a linear combination that includes that state.
Quantum Approximate Optimisation Algorithm
One last thing to take into account is that you are working with quantum states. This means that for random choice of parameters in your QAOA circuit, you will be generating complicated superposition of basis states. This is both good and bad news. On one hand this means that having a non-zero probability of measuring the optimal state is in general possible. On the other hand, the larger your parameter space and state space, the lower that probability will be. Without apparent structure in the problem, the probability of measuring that state may become exponentially small.
I believe that you are only simulating the circuit on a noiseless backend, but for completeness I'll add a comment on noise. In practice, you are also limited by the noise of your device. Measuring an output state will diverge from simulated values simply because all processes involved may error with a finite probability. Which means that even if you assume the circuit to be perfectly chosen and the optimisation to be perfectly executed, your result may very well exhibit a bit-flip at the output.
Hope this helps!
